# ¿Cómo puedo revertir únicamente las vocales de un string en PHP?

Tags: php, lógica

Empecé a realizar un pequeño ejercicio que invierte las letras de una palabra en string:

Ejemplo: *Hola > aloH*

```php
<?php
$palabra = "Hola";
$cuenta = strlen($palabra);
$invertida = "";

for ($i = $cuenta; $i >= 1; $i--) {
    $invertida .= $palabra[$i - 1];
}

echo $invertida;
?>
```

Lo que quiero hacer ahora es un código que invierta únicamente las vocales del *string*, ejemplo:

> Hola > Halo 
> Comer > Cemor 
> Cosa > Caso

¿Me podrían ayudar?

De antemano les agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Y qué problema tiene tu código? Anímate e inténtalo primero :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no me dí cuenta de ese error, ahora mismo lo corrijo! Lo que trato de buscar es alguna solución para invertir únicamente las vocales, no el texto completo... Gracias chicos!

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856930/5587982) en SO en inglés. Y para revertir una cadena entera PHP tiene una función nativa, se llama [`strrev()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strrev.php),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo así:

1. Recorremos la palabra desde la primer letra en adelante hasta encontrar una vocal.
2. A continuación recorremos la palabra desde la última letra hacia atrás hasta encontrar una vocal.
3. Intercambiamos posiciones entre ambas vocales.
4. Volvemos al paso 1 desde donde quedamos, hasta que ambos indices converjan.

#### Ejemplo:

```
function invertirVocales($palabra)
{
    $letras = mb_str_split($palabra);
    $ini = 0;
    $fin = count($letras) - 1;
    $vocales = '/[aeiouáéíóúü]/i';

    // PASO 1 - Recorremos desde la primera hasta la ultima
    for (; $ini < $fin; $ini++) {
        // Si es vocal
        $letraIni = $letras[$ini];
        if (preg_match($vocales, $letraIni)) {

            // PASO 2 - Recorremos desde la ultima hasta la primea
            for (; $fin > $ini; $fin--) {
                // Si es vocal
                $letraFin = $letras[$fin];
                if (preg_match($vocales, $letraFin)) {

                    // PASO 3 - Intercambiamos las vocales en las posiciones
                    $letras[$ini] = $letraFin;
                    $letras[$fin] = $letraIni;
                    $fin--;

                    // Volvemos al PASO 1, para continuar controlando
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return implode('', $letras);
}

echo invertirVocales('Hola')."\n"; // Halo
echo invertirVocales('Murciélago') . "\n"; // Morcaéligu
echo invertirVocales('Ombú')."\n"; // úmbO
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/51f848c0d065d4a56079704d997d2cf2ab7df85d)</kbd>

Comment: Wow! Qué buen método y muy entendible! De verdad muchas gracias por tu respuesta!